# How to create custom user without using models from django.contrib?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I've tried to create custom user for authentication purpose.

The problem is, django.contrib.auth.models are not flexible enough to be extended.

I'm using legacy mysql database with quite different table compared with django.contrib models. And I was told not to touch it by my boss since it's quite critical for our business.

To conclude, I want to know how to create custom user which should be mutually excluded from django.contrib models yet still functional enough for token authentication purposes.

I'm a beginner at Django, at I've yet found useful advices from official documentations.

Comment: So what you want is a brand new User model ? [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) provides many information about how to [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) and to [subtitute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) default User model.

Comment: What do you mean not flexible enough to be extended? `AbstractBaseUser` allows you to create a completely custom model. We use it along with DRF and the token authentication works just fine.

Comment: When I extend User model, it also tied to contrib.admin, contrib.session, and contrib.contenttype. I found it tedious and simply wrong to also migrate those apps to legacy database.

Comment: I think it is mandatory to use a model that is somehow linked to django contrib and so on because it uses its own authentication engine,... So if you don't want that I guess you'll have to write your own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a brand new model, you can create your own, based on AbstractUser, so that you can add whatever you want.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):

    # ... 
    # your new fields here
    # ...
```

If you are not allowed to do that and must use the default one, you can extend it with a new model that is linked to the default User with a [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField).

Comment: If I extend AbstractUser, somewhere along the way it will modify contrib.admin/contrib.session/contrib.contenttype tables. I feel that migrating those tables to legacy database is simply wrong from Django standards.

Comment: It usually happens when you tried to accessing admin page/destroying an user instance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? You have a legacy database that you want to import in a Django Project and for that you have to implement models that match the data that is in the database ?

Comment: Update: After I read more carefully I realized extending it with OneToOneField is the cleanest way to go. I accepted this answer and probably will share my implementation in github when I'm done creating it such that noone will get stuck in this tar-pit again.